# An array as state: state update re-renders all children in functional component with hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm rendering a huge list of words using the array.map function. Depending on the user input, I change individual array elements (only one at a time).

```
const [words, setWords] = useState();

let wordList = [];
wordList.push({ t: 'word1', a: 1, s: 0 });
wordList.push({ t: 'word2', a: 0, s: 0 });
wordList.push({ t: 'word3', a: 0, s: 0 });
wordList.push({ t: 'word4', a: 0, s: 0 });
wordList.push({ t: 'word5', a: 0, s: 0 });
...etc.
setWords(wordList);
```

in the return part:

```
...
    words.map((word, index) => (
      <Word key={index} word={word} index={index} />
    ))}
```

I run into performance issues as the whole list of words is rerendered on state change (which happens on every keystroke), even though it is only one element at a time and the index (which I use as the key) doesn't change.
Is this the default behaviour if you update a state that consists of an array? If so, how would you implement an array of states (each word is its own state), so you only update one state at a time, therefore only rerending the individual child that is connected to the state (or am I missing/misunderstanding something)?

Comment: if it doesn't make sense for each child to hold it's own state, have a look at [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: @Aprillion will take a look, thank you!